# How to set bydefault value of Picker in Xamarin form(MVVM)?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, mvvm, xamarin.forms

This is Xaml Code in which I am using a picker:

```
<Picker
    ItemsSource="{Binding AttendanceDateList}" 
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Date}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding AttendanceDate}"
    Title="Select">
</Picker>
```

and this is my MVVM code, here is my list, and model that is bound to the selected item. I have seen many solutions, but nothing worked.

```
public ObservableCollection<AttendanceDate> AttendanceDateList { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<MarkAttendance> AttendanceList {
    get
    {
        return _attendancelist;
    }
    set
    {
        _attendancelist = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => AttendanceList);
    }
}

public AttendanceDate AttendanceDate
{
    get
    {
        return _attendanceDate;
    }
    set
    {
        _attendanceDate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => AttendanceDate);
    }
}

AttendanceDateList = new ObservableCollection<AttendanceDate>()
{
    new AttendanceDate(){AttendanceDateId=0 ,Date="Last Seven Days"},
    new AttendanceDate(){AttendanceDateId=1,Date="Last Fifteen Days"},
    new AttendanceDate(){AttendanceDateId=2,Date="Last Thirty Days"},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the binding (which in in your case is AttendanceDate) with an existing element from the source list.

Example:

XAML

```
<Picker
  ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" 
  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Description}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}"
  Title="Select">
</Picker>
```

ViewModel

```
    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> TestList { get; set; }

    public TestModel SelectedTest { get; set; }

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        TestList = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>()
        {
            new TestModel { Description = "Last Seven Days"},
            new TestModel { Description = "Last Fifteen Days"},
            new TestModel { Description = "Last Thirty Days"},
        };

        SelectedTest = TestList[2];
    }
```

Model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "existing element from the source list" finally I was able to understand why my picker wasn't showing the selected item !

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` to use the picker default value.

**Solution1:**

Add the `attendanceDate = AttendanceDateList[0];` in your ViewModel.

The whole ViewModel:

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<AttendanceDate> AttendanceDateList { get; set; }

    public AttendanceDate _attendanceDate;
    public AttendanceDate attendanceDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _attendanceDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _attendanceDate = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("_attendanceDate"));
        }
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        AttendanceDateList = new ObservableCollection<AttendanceDate>()
{
  new AttendanceDate() { AttendanceDateId = 0 ,Date = "Last Seven Days"},
  new AttendanceDate() { AttendanceDateId = 1,Date = "Last Fifteen Days"},
  new AttendanceDate() { AttendanceDateId = 2,Date = "Last Thirty Days"},
};
        attendanceDate = AttendanceDateList[0];
    }


    public class AttendanceDate
    {
        public int AttendanceDateId { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Same xaml as yours:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Picker
        x:Name="picker"
        Title="Select"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Date}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding AttendanceDateList}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding attendanceDate}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Code Behild:

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ViewModel() ;
        //picker.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
```

**Solution2:**

No change with your ViewModel and the `SelectedIndex` in your xaml.

Code behind:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ViewModel() ;
        picker.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]